# Having jeditable save when focus is lost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

(How) can I tweak [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to save the text when focus is lost from the text area? If you don't supply submit/cancel buttons, then when pressing 'Enter' the content is saved ... but I haven't found how to save the content on focus lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `onblur` option, like this:

```
$('.editable').editable('myPage.php', {
  onblur: 'submit'
});
```

[Inside jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.js) this is what happens:

```
} else if ('submit' == settings.onblur) {
   input.blur(function(e) {
     t = setTimeout(function() { form.submit(); }, 200);
   });
}
```

There are detils for the `onblur` option [at the bottom of the jEditable post here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), just search for "onblur" in the page.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks - I guess I didn't reach the bottom of the jeditable page :)